# Writing JUnit test for a webservice that uses @EJB

Tags: java, junit, ejb

I have a restful web service that access data from a database and sends back a response and works fine.The web service currently uses an ejb that is deployed in the weblogic server.Is there a way I can write a JUnit test without an embedded EJB server(Arquillian) for this web service, taking into account the @EJB being used?Right now the unit test that I have written returns a NullPointer Exception as the EJB is not found.

Thanks